# Python STAR & HASH ODD DIAMOND print with recursion

Tags: python, recursion

[**I want to make a pattern as shown below:**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9skJJ.png)

I write this program which is given below. But I couldn't take ODD numbers. Could anybody please explain what the mistake is and what the solution is? Thanks.

```
*

def printPartten(n, k): 

    if (n < 0): # Base condition 
        return; 
    # Recursive call 
    printPartten(n - 1, k + 1);  
    for i in range(0, k): # it makes spaces 
        print(" ", end=""); 
    for i in range(0, n): # for print * 
        print("* ", end = ""); 
    print("\n", end=""); # for next line 
   def printPatternReverse(n, k): 
    if (n < 0): # Base condition 
        return; 
    for i in range(0, k): # it makes spaces 
        print(" ", end = "") 
    for i in range(0, n): # for print * 
        print("#", end = " ") 
    print("\n", end = "") # for next line 
    # Recursive calls 
    printPatternReverse(n - 1, k + 1);

# Call to printPartten function 
n = int(input("Please enter the desire value for N:  "))
printPartten(n, 0);
print("\n",end="")
printPatternReverse(n,0)
print("Thank You!!!")
```

*

[My Output like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccb0b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You example shows that it skips the even rows, so you could add a check for even rows using a modulus:

```
if (k % 2 == 0):
```

Applied to your code:

```
def printPartten(n, k):
    if (n < 0): # Base condition 
        return;
    # Recursive call
    printPartten(n - 1, k + 1); 
    if (k % 2 == 0):
        for i in range(0, k): # it makes spaces 
            print(" ", end=""); 
        for i in range(0, n): # for print * 
            print("* ", end = "");
        if (k > 0):
            print("\n", end=""); # for next line 
def printPatternReverse(n, k):
    if (n < 0): # Base condition 
        return; 
    if (k % 2 == 0):
        for i in range(0, k): # it makes spaces 
            print(" ", end = "") 
        for i in range(0, n): # for print * 
            print("#", end = " ")
        print("\n", end=""); # for next line 
    # Recursive calls 
    printPatternReverse(n - 1, k + 1);

# Call to printPartten function 
n = int(input("Please enter the desire value for N:  "))
printPartten(n, 0);
print("\n",end="")
printPatternReverse(n,0)
print("Thank You!!!")
```

Output:

```
Please enter the desire value for N:  9
        * 
      * * * 
    * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
# # # # # # # # # 
  # # # # # # # 
    # # # # # 
      # # # 
        # 
Thank You!!!
```